# Backfill data based or insert new records based on matching criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-merge

I have the following effective dated table with several thousands records that would need to be updated/inserted based on certain criteria.

Table `Car_Specification`:

| Effective_Date | Car_ID | Num_Wheels | Num_Doors | Engine_Type | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | Red |
| 01-APR-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | Blue |
| 01-JUN-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | Green |

Lookup `Car_Change`:

| Effective_Date | Car_ID | Num_Wheels | Num_Doors | Engine_Type | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | White |
| 01-MAY-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Manual | Red |

Every day, changes to a car is captured inside the `Car_Change` table and the updates will need to be updated into `Car_Specification` table based on `Car_ID` and `Effective_Date`.

In the example above, I would like to query `Car_Specification` for the list of `effective_date` and `car_id` and perform a lookup into `Car_Change` table, if a match based on `effective_date` and `car_id` is found, I will update the data in the `Car_Change` with the data in the `Car_Specification` table for those fields that matches. The changes will also need to be forward filled or propagated forward.

If the `effective_date` and `car_id` doesn't match but there is a change in `Car_Change`, I will need to insert the new effective_date and `car_id` into `Car_Specification` and forward fill the changes.

For instance, C001 will show the following after the update:

| Effective_Date | Car_ID | Num_Wheels | Num_Doors | Engine_Type | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-MAR-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | White |
| 01-APR-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Turbo | White |
| 01-MAY-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Manual | Red |
| 01-JUN-2021 | C001 | 4 | 2 | Manual | Red |

I am thinking along the line of using the MERGE UPDATE/INSERT construct to handle the changes. Would like to seek advice on the most efficient way to handle such changes given the tables are large and I am looking to do the update/insert operation on a daily basis to keep my data inside `Car_Specification` updated. If I am going ahead with MERGE, how do I handle the forward filling of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a frame challenge. Several thousands of records is a tiny data set; you do not need to merge the data. Just have a single row for each car in `Car_Specification` for the original specification and then if there are changes put them into `Car_Changes` and when you want to **display** the latest value then select the last change, or the specification if there were no changes.

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(c.effective_date, s.effective_date) AS effective_date,
       s.car_id,
       COALESCE(c.num_wheels, s.num_wheels) AS num_wheels,
       COALESCE(c.num_doors, s.num_doors) AS num_doors,
       COALESCE(c.engine_type, s.engine_type) AS engine_type,
       COALESCE(c.color, s.color) AS color
FROM   car_specification s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL(
         SELECT *
         FROM   car_changes c
         WHERE  c.car_id = s.car_id
         AND    c.effective_date >= s.effective_date
         ORDER BY c.effective_date DESC
         FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
       )
       ON (1 = 1) -- The join condition is inside the lateral join.
```

If you want you can wrap it in a view.